# +[GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, flutter

I have google maps pod installed in my app and using third party SDK which is internally using google maps. Whenever i am trying to enter to load Maps screen, it immediately crashing with below exception.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
> '+[GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]:
> unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100c90448'

When I remove that custom SDK and loading maps, it is successfully loading without crash.

Dont know what is the exact issue here. Suggestions would be helpful to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the `-ObjC` linker flag to the 'Build Settings' of your both the **project** and the **target**.

Comment: Already setted all neccessary steps. But no use.